# Turn off notifications of an app programatically on Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-package-managers

I am developing a package manager application which shows checkboxes to turn off notifications from different applications installed on the Android device.

[image: Turning off notifications of an app from Applications Manager]

Since Android 4.1, users can turn off notifications of an app from application manager. Can I turn on/off notifications from an app programatically? Is there an API for doing that?

Comment: How cruel it is that I have Android 4.0.4 and I can't turn off notifications. :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot do that from your code. Perhaps on rooted devices you could do some magic, but that shall not really count for wider audience.

Comment: For the rooted devices, XDA-developers have released a notification manager app. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2217572

Comment: But rooted devices are sparse and not so huge in volumes. This is not our targetbase for distributing the app.

Comment: Hi @Marcin Orlowski do you think android have introduce anything now a days for doing above thing ?

Comment: @RajeshPanchal I do not think so, otherwise muted app (esp. all these posting ads there) would most likely start spamming other way.

Answer (score -1):

If you are App dev, you should manage that on server side, having a webservice (REST API) allowing the user to unsubscribe to the notifications.
Then implement a Settings section in your App where user can uncheck a notification box and that call this service.
Then, your server will not send the notification to this user.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question clearly. Question is how to manage blocking all the notifications of other app(s) in your app programmatically

Comment: you didn't understood the question.